# vertical alignment in css

Tags: html, css

I am getting the following output with current arrangement.
[image]

I want the red words to align at same vertical position and produce the following result.
[image]

Comment: `vertically` or `horizontally`? You question doesn't make much sense. Also, where's the code involved?

Comment: `text-align: left` (default value) and `padding-left`, if you want to indent red labels from left side.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: @panther But if the content is large ,it aligns the content in the left. Look below image,how can I fix that? i.imgur.com/WRNNNtN.png

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML & CSS to reproduce the issue, ideally along with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @BrainyPrb: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575184/vertical-alignment-in-css/29575541#29575541) below, it should be what you are looking for. The wrapper element is centered depending on its content, no fixed widths or paddings are needed. Of course, you can use else HTML markup, I create fiddle using divs and spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which center the parent element (`#wrapper`). The width depends on children content.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <span>red label:</span>
        <span>value</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>second red label:</span>
        <span>loooooooooooong value</span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #wrapper {margin: 0 auto; display: table; background: #eee;}
    #wrapper div > span:first-child {color: red;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jag25xf5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `text-align: left`

Also check http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html and [text-align-CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: But if the content is large ,it aligns the content in the left. Look below image,how can I fix that? i.imgur.com/WRNNNtN.png

Comment: @BrainyPrb:- Can you provide a jsfiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align:left example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
 .text-left{
    text-align:left;
    width:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
 }
 p span{
    color:#F00;
    font-weight:600;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="text-left">
    <p><span>Label 1</span> Content</p>
    <p><span>Label 2</span> Content</p>
    <p><span>Label 3</span> Content</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But if the content is large ,it aligns the content in the left. Look below image,how can I fix that?
http://i.imgur.com/WRNNNtN.png

Comment: Updated example so it looks in middle by making use of the margin: 0 auto; as well as specifying the width.